# How can I return the current column name in columnDefs jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, columndefinition

Like this I can return the value of the current row:

```
"columnDefs": [

  {
    "render": function (data, type, row) {
     return data ;
 },
```

What I am actually looking for is the name of the current column.
I tried:

```
"columnDefs": [

  {
    "render": function (data, type, row) {
     return column().name ;
 },
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a `targets` in your `columnDefs` you could do the following by adding a `meta` parameter :

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        targets: 0,
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            var title = $('#example').DataTable().columns( meta.col ).header(); 
            var columnName = $(title).html();
            return columnName;
        }
    },
]
```

JSFiddle example (check the log) : https://jsfiddle.net/1jot32nz/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jarla happy to help!